# Javascript HAML engine

Tags: javascript, haml

I'm looking for a javascript 'port' of haml supporting the following features:

1. Templates stored in files.
2. JSON input.
3. Supports "collections" [{Booking},{Booking},{Booking}] for iterated processing.

Essentially I'd like the functionality as [sinatra_more](http://github.com/nesquena/sinatra_more)'s templates.

Does anyone know of something that fits the bill?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an old post, but just in case anyone gets here from google, it's worth mentioning [Jade](http://jade-lang.com/)

It's not strict haml, but a haml-inspired templating language for node and javascript

Answer (score 2):

The most up-to-date list of Haml implementations is on [the Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haml#Implementations). According to that, the only Javascript implementation of Haml is [haml-js](http://github.com/creationix/haml-js). I'm not sure how well this satisfies your requirements, but it's worth checking out.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't – and I think I'd rather build the elements myself anyway.

Comment: I already have a look to haml-js, but it does not respect the HAML reference :(
So I don't use it, even if for me HAML is the **way** to write HTML code.

Answer (score -1):

Why not use the HAML library on the backend to precompile your javascript-containing HAML templates to EJS?

I'll keep you posted if I implement this & release a gem or something.  I hope other kind developers will do the same if it proves too much for me.  :)